# Strange .htaccess ErrorDocument Error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i have the following line in my .htaccess file which is situated on my PC at `G:/xampp/htdocs/project/public_html/.htaccess`

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

So when I enter any non-valid address, for example `http://localhost/project/public_html/blabla` , the following message appears:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /project/public_html/blabla was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.3.4 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 Server at localhost Port 80
```

But this is not my 404.html page!

But when I edit the `ErrorDocument` Syntax and include full link, i.e. make it:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/project/public_html/404.html
```

but this redirects non existing links correctly to 404.html, but redirection is not what i want! I want a simple 404 error page!

Also one more strange thing is, when I remove the line completely from the .htaccess file, the error changes to this:

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
localhost
1/4/2013 4:27:46 PM
Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.3.4 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
```

creepy, eh? so could someone help me out and tell me whats going on please?

Comment: Just to make sure.... `404.html` is at the very top of your web root, correct?

Comment: root directory is `G:/xampp/htdocs/` , my 404.html is at `G:/xampp/htdocs/project/public_html/`

Comment: `/` references the web root, so I'm not sure why you would expect Apache to magically find that.  Try either changing the path to `/project/public_html/404.html` or moving the 404 to `/xampp/htdocs/`.

Comment: `/ references the web root, so I'm not sure why you would expect Apache to magically find that` I was thinking that / references to the folder .htaccess file is in. 

I tried your solution and it worked! thanks , could you please formulate this into an answer and post it so that I can accept it..

Comment: Sure :).  Have done so now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/` references the web root, so your paths don't quite make sense.  Either move the file to the web root, or change the path to reflect the path relative to the web root.  (Either move the file to `/xampp/htdocs`, or change the path to `/project/public_html/404.html`.)